# When does $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$ decompose into (some of) its simple submodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $A$-module, where $A$ is an associative algebra. We know that $M/\mathrm{rad}(M) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^m S_i$, where each $S_i$ is simple and $\mathrm{rad}(M)$ is the intersection of all maximal (proper) submodules of $M$. I am wondering when this decomposition comprises of simple submodules of $M$?

When $A$ is a symmetric algebra, and $P$ a projective indecomposable $A$-module, it is known that $\mathrm{soc}(P) \cong P/\mathrm{rad}(P)$, for instance.

For another consideration: take a projective indecomposable $R$-module $P$. It is a standard result that $P/\mathrm{rad}(P) \cong  S$, where $S$ is simple (sometimes referred to as the “top” of $P$). However, $S$ is not a submodule of $P$ in general.

I’m new to the area of commutative algebra, so do excuse my ignorance. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Oh yes, @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez, you're correct; I've edited the post, replacing $M$ in the second body of text with a projective indecomposable module $P$, which it is true for. (See Theorem 1.6.3 in Representations and Cohomology I, by Garling et al.)